# docker-compose healthcheck and depends_on service_healthy is super slow

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my mvp docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  first:
    image: alpine:latest
    entrypoint: sleep 100s
    healthcheck:
      test: sleep 1
      timeout: 2s
      start_period: 1s


  second:
    image: alpine:latest
    entrypoint: sleep 10s
    depends_on:
      first:
        condition: service_healthy
```

What I'd expect to happen:

1. start service *first* (might take a few seconds)
2. a second after the start, the `test sleep 1` should return, turning the service healthy
3. starting service *second* (might take a few seconds)
4. service *second* terminates after 10 more seconds

However what happens:

1. start service *first* (takes a few seconds)
2. ***nothing happens for some 30 seconds***
3. start service *second*
4. service *second* terminates after 10 more seconds

Where is my misconception that explains this huge difference?

*(I don't want a discussion, on weather having healthchecks and depends_on conditions are good practice ore not. That would not be on topic for this question)*

Answer (score 4):

The misconception is:

The default value for the parameter `interval` is `30s`.
And though the parameter `start_period` might suggest something different, the first health check is performed after that interval.

The `start_period` does not demark the time, the *healthchecks* start but instead the time, negative results would be considered not fatal.

Therefore it is impossible to define a sensible waiting time for the first health_check without providing unsensible intervals, the check is rerun during the whole life time.

Comment: There really should be a parameter for cold start max allowed healthcheck time and `interval` would then be only considered for health checks on running container.